# get label value on check of checkbox

Tags: jquery

my html :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="113" id="product_113" class="chk_product_name" name="product[parentid][childid][]">
<label for="product_113">Samsung<label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="114" id="product_114" class="chk_product_name" name="product[parentid][childid][]">
<label for="product_114">Nokia<label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="115" id="product_115" class="chk_product_name" name="product[parentid][childid][]">
<label for="product_115">Apple<label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="116" id="product_116" class="chk_product_name" name="product[parentid][childid][]">
<label for="product_116">LG<label>
```

i just want to get value of each label on checked of checkbox
i try this in jquery :

```
$('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]').click(function(){            
    $('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]:checked').each(function() {
        alert($("label:for:product_"+this.value).html );
    });         
});
```

[**see this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq4C2/)

Comment: You need to use `.change` in stead of `.click` to look for the checkbox event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your label tag. Use

```
<label for="product_113">Samsung</label>
```

instead of

```
<label for="product_113">Samsung<label>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]').click(function () {
    $('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]:checked').each(function () {
        alert($("label[for='product_" + this.value + "']").html());
        //OR
        alert($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').html());
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq4C2/5/)

Additionally, I would suggest you to use `change` event instead of `click`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this , [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq4C2/1/)

Also don't forget to close 'label' tag

```
$('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]').click(function () {
    alert($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]').click(function () {
    $('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]:checked').each(function () {
        alert($("label[for='product_" + $(this).val()+"']").html());
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Tq4C2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is short, readable and clean

```
$('.chk_product_name').change(function(){ 
  if (this.checked){ alert($('label[for='+this.id+']').text());}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much shorter version: **http://jsfiddle.net/Tq4C2/7/**

```
$('[name="product[parentid][childid][]"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

Your `<label>` tag's were not closed either.